# Can I change the voice of Google Translate in different gender?

Tags: text-to-speech, google-translate

Through some excellent answers I know I can get the MP3 file from text input by using the following URL with properties:

http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=zh-TW&q=我要吃餅乾

But the voice on the MP3 is female (I'm using Chinese).

Can I get the voice output on different gender by give additional properties like:

http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=zh-TW&q=我要吃餅乾&gender=male

Anyone knows? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm, I recall it being a male voice not too long ago, but now it is female. It seems they change it sometimes for no apparent reason. (The voice in Google searches [like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Atest) are still male.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was looking for the same, but after doing some research, there is no way to configure the voice. Neither pitch, speed nor gender. The Google TTS API is unofficial, that's why there is unsupported.